# Why should you use ACL in CakePHP instead of authentication with a user level feature?

Tags: cakephp, acl

Having difficulty seeing the advantage of going through all the trouble with ACL when I could do it myself.

Comment: Explain 'do it myself' some more.

Comment: For instance, use a user_level field in the users table and tie in a " if(user_level >= 5) then do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best reason to use an ACL system is that access requirements may change. A check for user_level > 5 is what is needed now, but it may change in the future. There is a higher level of abstraction in checking if a role is allowed a certain action because it is not tied to a condition. This condition is thus allowed to change over time.

Comment: Thanks koen and dogmatic69, your combined answer solved my question. Can you recommend a good guide for making acl beyond stock for CakePHP? Having a difficult time getting it going

Answer (score 1):

If you use acl you can create a backend to manage it so when you hand your project over the end user can do it them self without needing to know code.

It is also mor DRY so if for example you had to add a new user type you can just add new rows to the db instead of having to hack it into your code